# Determine all duplicates in array of size n having values in range 0 to n-2 in O(1) space and O(n) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, duplicates

An integer array of size n is given. It can only contain values in the range 0 to n-2 inclusive. There can be multiple duplicates in the array. Is there a way to determine all the possible duplicates in O(n) time and O(1) space without modifying the array?

There is algorithm [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/), but that modifies the array. There is another algorithm [here](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=find-duplicate), but from what i can see it determines only one of the duplicates. Is there a way to determine all the duplicates?

Comment: No, with O(1) space limitation. To determine all possible duplicates you'll need new array with size up to N to store duplicates (f.e. N same elements; or N/2 pair elements).

Comment: The second link describes a simpler version of the problem, and claims that it took Donald Knuth 24 hours to solve. Are you sure your more difficult version is correct?

Comment: The first can be done because it's on the trail from n-1. Other duplicates won't have this property, so I am skeptical that anyone will be able to provide a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in the array were arbitrary, I don't think there would be *any* way to do it in less than O(n<sup>2</sup>).

However, I'd be looking very carefully at that limitation on the data, that the possible values must be drawn from `0` through `n-2`. That allows you to introduce an efficiency which, while I don't think will get you back from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n), will at least greatly improve the *run-time* of your algorithm.

Here's how it works. Consider the ten numbers all drawn from the range `0..9`:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Now introduce a duplicate:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 8 9
```

The one thing you should notice is that the introduction of a duplicate has caused a hole to open up in the set of numbers used - there is no longer a `7` in the list.

In fact, for every duplicate you introduce, a *possible* value disappears entirely, and you can use that fact to optimise your algorithm. The trick here is to not search the list for *every* possible number but to use each search to also figure out the *next* number you should be looking for (the lowest number which is greater than the current number). Consider the 13-element list:

```
{0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 7, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9}
```

So first, we search for `0`. We find it's a duplicate but we *also* find that the next possible number is `1` so we remember that for the next phase.

Ditto for the next couple of iterations where we search for `1` (duplicate) and the next is `2`, then search for `2` (unique) and the next is `3`.

But here it gets interesting. When we search for `3` (duplicate), we find that the next possible number is actually `7` so we can totally skip `4`, `5` and `6`. And, of course, we skip `8` for the same reason (when searching for `7`, we find the next is `9`).

When we search for the `9`, there is no next possible term so we can stop at that point.

In pseudo-code<sup>1</sup>, that would be something like:

```
list = [0,1,1,1,2,3,0,7,9,3,9,3,9]
n = len(list)

# Initial search term and begin loop for each term.

currN = 0
while currN <= n - 2:
    print ("Checking for %d"%(currN))

    # Next search term, initially beyond max, and dupe detector.

    nextN = n
    count = 0

    # Check every list value.

    for val in list:
        # Count occurrences.

        if val == currN:
            count += 1

        # Update next search term if needed. If no value
        #   between curr and n, nextN will remain at n
        #   and loop will exit.

        if val > currN and val < nextN:
            nextN = val

    # Inform if duplicated and move to next search term.

    if count > 1:
        print ("%d is duplicated"%(currN))

    currN = nextN
```

---

There is also another possible optimisation if you want even more performance. At the moment, you're checking *every* value in the list on each iteration but that's not necessary.

For example, once you've checked for `0`, there's no point ever checking the first index `{0}` again since it will never again have an effect on the outcome.

Similarly, once you've checked `1`, you never need to revisit the first four elements `{0, 1, 1, 1}` again.

So there's advantage to be had by remembering not just the next possible search term but also the earliest possible point where you could find it, so that later iterations process less elements in their search.

The way that would work is that you would search from a variable spot, initially at the start of the list. However, on each pass, you would update this spot to be the *first* item in the list that is greater than the search term you're currently processing.

---

As stated, I don't believe either of these suggestions will give you O(n) but it's certainly better than the naive approach. It will range from close to `n * n` operations for the case where there's no duplicates (e.g., `{1, 2, 3, 4}`), down to about `n` operations where there is only a single duplicated value in the list (e.g., `{1, 1, 1, 1}`).

The more duplicates, the better will be the run-time.

---

<sup>1</sup> ... which looks suspiciously like Python3 code :-)